# Preventing onchange being triggered on an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onchange

It is possible to prevent onchange event being triggered?
I want to prevent it in any case(such as loosing focus on input) and trigger it only when I do it manually like:

`$('#my_input_id').val('a value').change()`;

Comment: Why not instead trigger a custom event??? Or just call a function when needed? Anyway, it sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: When a javascript onchange event is triggered , an linked Ajax based function in my controller submits the data.I want to prevent this and control when the function in my controller is called.Mention that the function is called only when the javascript onchange is called.

Comment: So if you don't want to send data on input change, why in first place are you setting this logic inside change event handler? Maybe i miss something but this is really unclear what you are talking about

Comment: Because I have a datepicker on that input and it does not trigger onchange automatically when I pick the date with the mouse.So i should force it in the datepicker event function .On the other hand , when I modify the date in the input with the keyboard it triggers onchange and also enters on the event function where i forced onchange. So i have the problem that my controller function is called twice when modifying the date with the keyboard.I want to block onchange event when focusout the input , because is already triggered in the datepicker event function.

Comment: Again, instead of asking question regarding any workaround, you would have better to re-ask new question regarding the fact that `it does not trigger onchange automatically when I pick the date with the mouse` because it should.  But which datepicker plugin are you talking about? Or are you using native HTML5 input date? Anyway, you have to provide MCVE

Comment: Now I understand your point,I agree,but before asking this I had tried to.I know it should but it simply does not. www.daterangepicker.com . this one.

Comment: idk how you trigger the onchange with your datepicker, but you can triggerit with a parameter and do apropriate stuff following this parameter

Comment: The datepicker does not triggers onchange because it has set `autoUpdateInput: false`

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your problem, here is my solution :

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="inp">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="trigger change">
```

JQuery :

```
$("#inp").change(function(e, data) {
  if (data) {
    console.log("change by trigger");
  } else {
    console.log("normal change");
  }
})

$("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#inp").val("12").trigger("change", true);
})
```

[LIVE DEMO JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z2erL76f/)

Comment: This still triggers a "normal change" . I don't want to enter through change function at all despite of having or not a functionality.

Comment: @MoroianuAlexandru are you looking for `e.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: Yes something like that but I don't know how to use it exactly. I tried to preventDefault() onfocusout but it still triggers onchange.

Comment: @MoroianuAlexandru  `$("#you_id").change(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); // do stuff })`

Comment: Tried. Still triggers onchange.

Comment: @JaxTeller There is no default behaviour for input change event

Comment: @MoroianuAlexandru i don't rly understand what you need, with my first answer, you can catch "normal change" and then doing stuff you need. And btw, you can't achieve it by using "focusout" or something, because change is called before the focus out.

Comment: I wrote in the comments of the question why I don't want to enter the onchange function at all.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set this inside your event:

```
if (en==1){
//code here
en=0;
}
```

and just set the en before manually calling the function

```
en=1;
$('#my_input_id').val('a value').change()
```

we set en back to zero in the end so we don't accidentally re-enable it. Ops